Quotation marks in dialogue for speech spoken by myself
In a dialogue between myself and other characters,  should I use quotation marks on my own words?
Example:

"Clean the dishes ", my mom said.
I'll clean them later, I replied.


Be consistent. Either enclose all dialogue in quotation marks or leave all dialogue without quotation marks, but do not mix the two. That kind of inconsistency will confuse your readers.
The convention in English fiction is to enclose dialogue in quotation marks:

“Clean the dishes,” my mom said.
“I'll clean them later,” I replied.

(Note that the comma goes inside the closing quotation mark.)
Usually whatever is outside of quotation marks and sounds like direct speech is thoughts:

“Clean the dishes,” my mom said.
“I'll clean them later,” I replied. No, I thought to myself. I won't.

Here, the first speech by the first person character ("I'll clean them later.") is spoken aloud to the mother, while the second "speech" ("No, I won't.") is spoken internally, in his or her mind. The convention is to italicize thoughts to distinguish them from the surrounding narration:

“Clean the dishes,” my mom said.
“I'll clean them later,” I replied. No, I won't.

Some languages have other conventions to indicate direct speech. For example, in Polish the convention is to use an em-dash:

— Clean the dishes, my mom said.
— I'll clean them later, I replied.

Some English-writing writers have experiemented with the quotation dash or not used any kind of quotation marker at all:

Clean the dishes, my mom said.
I'll clean them later, I replied.

The convention is to use quotation marks, but you are free to use any other style. Just be consistent. (And note that many agents and publishers will see a deviation from the convention with a critical eye, especially from previously unpublished writers and especially for popular fiction.)

I suspect that part of your confusion comes from the fact that both the dialogue and the narration seem to be said by you. You are who says "my mom said" and you are who says "I'll clean them later".
Imagine you are telling some friend about what happened. That telling will go something like this:

You walk up to your friend and say: "Do you know what happened yesterday?"
"No," your friend replies. "What?"
"Yesterday," you explain, "my mom came into my room and said, clean the dishes. And I said, I'll clean them later."

As you tell the story, you say both what your mom said and what you said, but it is clear to your friend and yourself, that you are not actually talking to your mom right now.
The story as a whole is what you say (or write) now. You narrate the story (including the dialogue). What you said at the time, when your mom asked you to do the dishes, and that you said it, are both part of the narrated story. You don't actually say it to your mom now (in the moment that you tell or write the story), you recount it just as you recount the speech of your mom. You cite your past self.
Or in other words, you-the-writer-now are not you-the-character-in-the-story-of-your-past. You tell a story about yourself, and that yourself-the-character is no different than your-mom-the-character or Harry Potter or Hamlet. Whatever a character says in a story is dialogue, and you need to distinguish it from your (the narrator's) descriptions, explanations, and so on. It doesn't matter if that character is a past version of you or some other person.
You might be confused about the use of quotation marks for "yourself", because you confuse yourself (the author of the text) with the first person viewpoint character in the text.
It is important for you to understand that you (the author) and "I" (the narrator) are not the same. It is obvious that Suzanne Collins, the author of The Hunger Games, isn't Katniss Everdeen, although she writes that book in the first person.
The narrator is a function of your text. Even in an autobiographical narrative the authore employs the first person narrator to achieve a certain effect: in this case, that of giving the impression of identity: the writer of an autobiography wants the reader to believe that he or she actually experienced what they wrote, even if they paint themselves in a better light or outright lie. Remember, just because you write "I said" doesn't necessarily mean that you actually said that. That "I" is a fiction, even if it is "you".
You can write autobiography in the third person, although that is unconventional, and you can write fiction in the first person. No matter which grammatical person you use, and no matter what you write about, you, the writer, are not the character in the text. That character, and the narrator, are functions of your writing that you employ to achieve a certain effect.

Summarized as: quote-marks for what is said aloud. Right?

Yes, you need to.
You're quoting what you said in the exchange.
There's no difference in how one handles direct speech when it's the narrator talking versus the other characters.
(There could be a difference if the others were speaking out loud but the narrator communicated telepathically or something, but then the difference would be in the telepathy, not the speaker.)

Ben's answer covers the usual conventions, but it's really up to you. However, when deciding on your own orthographic style, you should always keep in mind three critical considerations:
1. Have I made it easy for the reader to work out what's going on in the text?
This is a basic condition. If the reader has to flick back a few paragraphs to work out who's speaking, you've failed your primary task as a writer, and your reader is likely to give up and stop reading.
It's ok to be unconventional, but the reader must still be able to adjust to your style without too much effort. Your example – with narrator's dialogue in bold – works ok, but you'll have to make sure that bold text is reserved for the narrator only and is only used for spoken dialogue. Otherwise, the reader will become confused.
2. Have I been consistent with my stylised approach?
Again, consistency is a basic condition. A reader brings with them a package of expectations on how the text will be presented to them, but they will probably have been exposed to a range of styles and should be able to adapt to your own non-conventional approach if it meets Consideration #1. However, the moment you lapse in consistency, you risk confusing the reader, leading to frustration and potential abandonment.
3. Am I self-publishing?
If you are, then the only editor you have to work with is yourself. This is wonderfully artistically liberating: you can be as individually stylised or innovative as you like! However, it also means you'll probably need to pay someone if you want a professional pair of eyes to do a text edit that would pick up any stylistic inconsistencies (as well as them perhaps doing a structural edit, and/or proofreading your final draft).
Your choice of route to publication is a critical consideration, because if you plan on submitting your work to a publishing house, you'll need to take into account their likely resistance to non-conventional style. It's hard enough to get an editor to even look at your beautiful draft, let alone get through the first 10 pages and be interested enough to persevere with your idiosyncratic dialogue tags. It will be even harder – if they decide your draft warrants serious consideration – for you to insist on retaining your non-conventional orthography, since your prospective editor will also be contemplating how hard their own task will be to pitch your unconventional draft to their boss. They'll therefore be working hard to bring your draft back to within the conventional boundaries.
Yes, there are well-known published works with non-conventional dialogue tags or other unusual orthography. Emily Dickinson's poetry has idiosyncratic punctuation; Cormac McCarthy's novels are known for his sparse use of punctuation; and the last chapter of Joyce's Ulysses employs virtually no punctuation and is particularly hard to read. But these are exceptional writers. We mere mortals must deliver drafts that mostly conform to our publisher's conventions.

I believe the bold text in the question is just to point out what part of the example OP is asking about.

@Ben ah, yes, that's probably more likely. In which case the distinction between the narrator's dialogue and other text is less apparent, and the reader's task is a bit more difficult: 1st-person dialogue uses Cormac McCarthy's "unquoted" style, while other-person dialogue uses conventional "quotation" style. Albeit with typo (space before closing quotation mark) and non-conventional positioning of the comma after the quotation mark. Messy. PS: +1 for your answer :-)

And +1 for your answer :-)
